# Cannot filter a long field in Elasticsearch 5

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem with Elasticsearch. **vid** is a long field in my index. I try to search with:

```
POST my-index/video/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "vid": 6518061120253592000
    }
  }
}
```

but get nothing. Try with other fields (not long type), it's successful.
I'm sure that the document is existed in Elasticsearch.

My Elasticsearch version is 5.4.0

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the root cause here:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15292